# Basement moisture: condensation or leak?

Tags: plumbing, leak, pump, condensation

I have a significant amount of moisture built up in our unfinished basement that’s originating from the well water pump.

I’m trying to decide if it’s even possible that the moisture could be a slow build-up from condensation or if the symptoms are common for some sort of leak underneath.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: that is one strange view. What am I looking at ?

Comment: There does not seem to be a pump visible here, just a pipe and a pressure tank and a lot of extraneous crud. Are you quite sure your pump isn't submerged in the well?

Comment: If that light is suppose to be on the ceiling, you have a leak, maybe from outside.  Condensation will only make a small area under it damp, very rare for it to go up walls also.  The tank which condensation should form on looks dry.

Comment: Condensation on a tank and the pipes is normal where high humidity and warm air come into contact with the cool well water piping and pressure tank , covering the piping with pipe insulation and the pressure tank with a tight fitting insulating blanket then there won’t be condensation developing. a dehumidifier may be needed and sealing the floor can help reduce the humidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a small leak, quite hard to make out much detail in the picture.

A simple answer (except it delays and then complicates getting to fixing the probable leak) is that if you insulate the pipe and tank, and the drip stops, it was condensation. Or if you run a dehumidifier here and the drip **stops** (not just becomes less noticeable as it evaporates) it was condensation.

But it's probably a leak. That would be a LOT of condensation.